# Import all modules in one folder and use them by one of its attributes

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to build a modulable application, so I need a method that allows me to create new modules without modifying the main app. To do this I'm preparing module system that allows me to import all the module from a folder, and I want to select the module to use, by using a class attribute, for example.

The modules:

`topology_O.py`:

```
class Topology(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'O'
        self.version = 0.1

    def __str__(self):
        string = "Topology: " + self.name
        string += "Version: " + str(self.version)
        return string
```

`topology_H.py`:

```
class Topology(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'H'
        self.version = 0.1

    def __str__(self):
        string = "Topology: " + self.name
        string += "\n > Version: " + str(self.version)
        return string
```

I would like to use them like this:

```
myTopology = some_topology_thing('O')
print  myTopology
# Topology: O
#  > Version: 0.1

myTopology = some_topology_thing('H')
print  myTopology
# Topology: H
#  > Version: 0.1
```

So the modules will be selected and used by `name`.

Comment: I suppose you also want to import the required required module as well based on the `name` attribute?...just like `some_topology_thing('O')` --> Auto import topology_O...?

Comment: @IronFist yes that is what I need

Comment: Then I believe Mike Müller's one will be the same I would post .. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[importlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#module-importlib) can help here:

```
import importlib

def some_topology_thing(topo_type):
    mod = importlib.import_module('topology_{}'.format(topo_type))
    return mod.Topology()
```

Comment: If you were just a little bit patient...I would answer the same way...:/ ... too bad

Comment: Looks like a decent answer than as you came up with the same solution. ;)

Comment: Yea...because it happened I read a few months ago about `importlib` module as I was trying to understand the import mechanism...and what other way to import...anyway...this should be the right way for OP in my humble opinion..

Comment: I had found my own solution using `imp` module but yours its simpler, elegant and faster ;), thank you very mush

Comment: From the docs of `imp`: *In most cases it is preferred you consider using the `importlib` module's functionality over this module.*

Answer (score 1):

My own Solution

```
import os
import imp
from glob import glob

def some_topology_thing(topology):
    topologys = {}

    module_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'topologys')
    modules = glob(module_path + '/*.py')

    for i in modules:
        foo = imp.load_source('', i)
        topologys.update({foo.Topology().name: i})

    try:
        return imp.load_source('', topologys[topology]).Topology()
    except ImportError:
        print "Error: no topology \'" + topology + "\' Found"
        print "Available topologys are: " + str(topologys.keys())
```

Comment: Catching every exception is not really favorable, I think you better catch the exception you only think it will raise it, for ease of debugging, as: `except ImportError:`